# How to show prompt as the default text in EnumDropDownList when Enum is nullable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, enums, html.dropdownlistfor

For example, when enum is...

```
    public enum TaskFrequency
    {
        Weekly,
        [Display(Name = "Bi-weekly")]
        Biweekly,
        Monthly,
        Quarterly
    }
```

Used in ViewModel, like...

```
    [Display(Name = "Processing frequency", Prompt = "Select frequency")]
    public Enums.TaskFrequency? ProcessingFrequency { get; set; }
```

Implement like (in custom editor Enum.cshtml)...

```
    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model,
        optionLabel: ViewData.ModelMetadata.Watermark)
```

Expected behaviour:

[image]

Expected behavior:  Show the prompt if value is null (declaration nullable), and also show this in the list.  If non-nullable (required), then show the prompt, but do not include in select list items.  Expected that in case of non-nullable, that validation should be required to be sure there is no null going back to the server for update to the model.

See this fiddler for [desired behaviour](https://jsfiddle.net/cox/u29uyayf/3/).  What is actually happening is either [blank item in list](https://jsfiddle.net/cox/u29uyayf/4/) when nullable and no placeholder being used, or the optionLabel becomes [another list item](https://jsfiddle.net/cox/u29uyayf/4/) and is not used as any placeholder.

**EDIT / SOLULTION:**

It appears like the EnumDropDownListFor helper is less helpful than it could be.  What I have settled on as a solution is to use enum with first (0 based) item as the "Unselected" item with [Display(Name="Select item")] decorator, and then declare in the ViewModel class enum type as required (omitting the '?' on type name) and then defaulting the data values in table with '0'.

For example...

Enum:

```
    public enum TaskFrequency
    {
        [Display(Name = "Select frequency")]
        Unselected,
        Weekly,
        [Display(Name = "Bi-weekly")]
        Biweekly,
        Monthly,
        Quarterly
    }
```

ViewModel class declaration ('?' and Prompt removed):

```
    [Display(Name = "Processing frequency"]
    public Enums.TaskFrequency ProcessingFrequency { get; set; }
```

And remove the optionLabel from custom editor Enum.cshtml, leaving:

```
    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model)
```

Using customer editor (above), can use in View like:

```
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Frequency)
```

I'm open to any better ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding the `[Required]` attribute to the ProcessingFrequency property?

Comment: thanks.  Will investigate how this adds to the mix of behaviour logic.  However, me wonders if I just remove nullable marker on the declaration, this becomes a "required".  I still think the expected default behaviour of this helper needs work, or I am not implementing things correctly, in which case it needs work because it's just not intuitive.  ;-)

Comment: That's a way of solving it. However, I believe your enum member should not be clled "Unselected". By doing this, you are injecting UI behaviour into your model. 
I would name it sth like "None"

Answer (score 0):

Selects don't support a placeholder or descriptive value. What MVC does is add an additional option to the select list in the form of:

```
 <option value="">Select frequency</option>
```

This is a valid option like any other, though, so there's nothing inherently available to stop a user from choosing it. This is where validation comes in. If the posted value is null or empty, meaning the user either chose `Select frequency` explicitly or left it at the default state of selected, then, it's treated as a null value. If your property is non-nullable, or nullable but required (via the `[Required]` attribute), then an error will be added to the model state.

Comment: @Pratt.  True.  Why, by default (without coding), does this not because the selected item (or text) to prompt selection?  Though, it seems like a workaround to have to go set the default value to 0, where the declared is nullable.  This post is either a plea for what would be expected default behaviour as well as an inquiry into what settings or use to implement such which I am unaware.  For example, if setting a "Prompt" which adds the item, why must it be necessary to set optionLabel to have this become an item?  This should be default behaviour.

Comment: Frankly, I've never even paid attention to the `Prompt` property on `DisplayAttribute` before. I'm assuming it must have some purpose in native apps and/or something like Silverlight, where you have true controls and not just HTML. As far as I'm aware, it has no use in MVC.

Comment: CORRECTION:  in first line, 'because' should be 'become'